# Buddy kick 125 cc

Tags: scooter, wheel-balance

Rode it this morning and all was fine.  Got on it this afternoon and it feels unstable like the front end has a bobble?

Comment: Lump on the tire. Loose wheel nuts? Check the simple things before you ride again. Otherwise you could get hurt.

Comment: Also check your tire pressure.